# My ocelot in Minecraft won't change?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have it tamed, but it still doesn't follow me. It just walks away after I feed it.   I stayed away from it (about 10 or 5 blocks) and didn't move so it would come to me, I fed it fish and red hearts formed above, and after that, as soon as I started to leave it didn't follow me, or wear the collar or anything. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: Do you know which version of Minecraft you're playing? In the latest versions of Minecraft [ocelots can no longer be tamed or leashed](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Ocelot#History) as Cats and Ocelots are different mobs.

Comment: Note that the currently highest voted answer over there is outdated. Look at the others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's supposed to happen. Starting with Minecraft 1.14 (the Village&Pillage update) ocelots can no longer be tamed, won't turn into cats when tamed, and the only thing giving them fish does is make them willing to breed. Cats are now completely independent mobs that spawn randomly in villages.

(What the game recognizes as village has changed too, so all the old, pre-1.14 villages no longer count as such. But you can 'convert'/'restore' an old village quite easily as long as there are villagers alive - just add beds in all houses.)